# What should I do about this unfinished corner?

Tags: drywall, doors, walls, plaster

I've got this bit next to my back door that looks like it was never properly finished. There doesn't seem to be any structural issue, so I'd feel comfortable fixing it myself.

Trouble is, I have no idea what to do there. Plaster a corner? Put some drywall in? It's a strange shape and I am not sure where to start.

[image: An unfinished corner.]

[image: A closer view.]

EDIT: As requested, a picture of the top corner and the left side. (This is really a lovely house, overall, I swear! Despite the insanity of a few things like this)

[image: Top right corner]

[image: Left side]

Comment: Am I correct in seeing the unfinished wall on 2 surfaces? One about 2 or 3 inches wide beside the door and the other wall has about an inch or 2 needing finish? Is that an existing piece of trim that is called cove molding above the area in question? If that was run all the way to the floor would that correct it? In my opinion, it looks like a little mud work is needed, including the area where the existing trim is. Last question, is the partial trim at the top, the same on the other side?

Comment: is that exposed concrete or foam next to the door jam?

Comment: also, what type of molding is around the top and striker side of the door?

Comment: could you add a pic of the upper corner where the top of the door meets the wall?

Comment: You'll probably want to match the trim on the left side of the door if there is any. If there is trim there, but you're still unsure what to do on the right side, you should post a picture of the left side so we can see what you already have.

Comment: Pics added! Looking at the top, there's obviously a bit to do there as well. The left side is completely different, as often happens in old houses I suppose.

Comment: @getterdun there is a narrow wooden frame around the door which has been painted green on the opposite side. Painting that bit all the same would be a good finishing touch— now just to decide if I should plaster up that space or do some drywall ninja-ing

Comment: @Jack that existing piece is a random bit of wood which I think was just jammed in there to cut down on drafts. It is definitely going to go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will be a variation of what may have been mentioned already, but this is how I would handle it.

For the tall vertical piece, assemble 2 pieces of 1X material to make an outside corner that will mimic the left side wall where it meets the door. At the top add an additional piece of 1X to fill the void at the wood joist or beam at the top of the door. The idea is to bring the new material out in the same plane so when it is all painted out, it all looks like the same wall around the door. The only difference being new surfaces next to the older surfaces. The illustration will help depict what I mean, take note of the stunning green parts of the drawing that is referred to[image: door1]
[image]

Comment: The green is for highlighting purposes, the intent is it will be painted the same color as the wall when done. The beam can be rewrapped to conceal wires too...

Comment: I agree with this answer: trim it out. There is no way to use plaster or drywall to make it look natural. Trim is supposed to be a transition, which is exactly what you need in this small area. Besides, thin strips of drywall with corner beads are really hard to get right. I did this next to my main shower due to some old, constricted framing. Took me a week to mud it even, and it still was not close to perfect. My wife hates it.